# Como acceder a los elementos obtenidos en ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo ajax:

```
$.ajax(
      {
        data: {dni:id},
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>User/Userajax/",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function(res){
          console.log(res);
        },
        error: function () {
           console.log("error");
       }
      }
    );
```

y lo que imprime el console.log(res) es lo siguiente:

```
string(7) "1111111"
[{"nombre":"Emiliano","apellido":"Ibarra","dni":"1111111","nacimiento":"2018-07-22","celular":"12312312312","email":"aaaaemiibarraa@hotmail.com","direccion":"Alsina 725","FechaRegistro":"2021-05-03","nombreLocalidad":"Guamini","nombre_estado":"En lista de espera","nombreCarrera":"Ingenieria en Sistemas","institucion":"UNS","localidad":"dasdasd","cantanio":"11"}]
```

Intente todas las formas posibles, me esta quemando la cabeza esto.

intente: res[0].nombre
res.nombre

entre otros que no recuerdo.

EDIT PEGO URL:

```
  // verificamos si el dni se paso correctamente.
//      Mira en el inspector de elementos ->network y dale click al evento del ajax y mira el response. cuando estes seguro que es lo que necesitas quitas el var_dump();
//
var_dump($_POST["dni"]);

//
//

$id = $_POST["dni"];

if (is_null($id) && count($id) < 1)
  exit(json_encode(array("msg"=>"Ha sucedido un evento inesperado")));

$this->db->select('nombre,apellido,dni,nacimiento,celular,email,direccion,FechaRegistro,nombreLocalidad,nombre_estado,nombreCarrera,institucion,localidad,cantanio');
$this->db->from('usuario');

//
// en cada instruccion donde usas el join debes colocar
// hacia adonde se van a emparejar los registros.
//

$this->db->join("registro", "registro.dni_registro = usuario.dni");
$this->db->join("localidad", "localidad.idLocalidad = usuario.Idlocalidad");
$this->db->join("beca", "beca.dni_beca = usuario.dni");
$this->db->join("estado_beca", "estado_beca.id = beca.estadoBeca");
$this->db->where(
  array(
    'dni'=>$id
  )
);

$qry = $this->db->get();
$rslt = ($qry->num_rows() > 0) ? $qry->result("array") : "No se ha encontrado registros con el actual DNI";

exit(json_encode($rslt));
```

copio las ultimas tres lineas que ahi es como lo devuelvo, antes de eso estan las consultas a la base de datos pero con eso no hay problema porque retorna datos correctamente.

EDIT2 agrego preview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La respuesta del servidor viene en JSON. Antes de tratar de accederla, debes pasarla por `JSON.parse`. Añade `JSON.parse(res)` en la línea antes de tu `console.log(res)`

Comment: Holaaa muestra tu codigo que tenes en tu url de ajax asi podremos ver como la estas retornando, quiza solo estas retornando texto

Comment: @CamiloGomez lo hice y no funciona.

Comment: @WilsonFreddyAndiaAlborta ahi lo edito....

Comment: Asignaste el `JSON.parse(res)` a otra variable y trataste de imprimirla?
`const parsed = JSON.parse(res)
console.log(parsed)
` ?

Comment: @CamiloGomez Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Comment: si agrego al ajax dataType: "json", no me ejecuta el success. Ejecuta error.

Comment: Estas colocando en tu cabezera de tu url que vas a devolver un json?...
`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: Parece que estás imprimiendo el DNI antes de enviar la respuesta y eso hace que el resultado no pueda interpretarse como JSON.

Comment: @Triby modifique y tampoco funciona....

Comment: @gisela, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas en el servidor y la salida que obtienes después de la modificación.

Comment: @Triby listo. Ahi ya esta editada.

Comment: Parece que retornas un array con json valido en el primer lugar. Puedes intentar `const parsed = JSON.parse(res[0]); console.log(parsed)` y ver si funciona?

Comment: @CamiloGomez SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En PHP quita la línea `var_dump($_POST['dni']);`, porque esa hace que no se devuelva un JSON válido y también modifica el resultado para que siempre devuelvas algo que puedas interpretar:

```
$qry = $this->db->get();
$rslt = ($qry->num_rows() > 0) ? $qry->result("array") : array("msg" => "No se ha encontrado registros con el actual DNI"];
```

En la petición AJAX solo agrega `dataType: 'json'` para especificar que los datos recibidos vienen en JSON:

```
$.ajax(
  {
    data: {dni:id},
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>User/Userajax/",
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res){
      console.log(res);
      // Analizar si hubo errores
      if(res.hasOwnProperty('msg')) {
          // Mostrar mensaje de error
          console.log('Error: ' + res.msg);
      } else {
          // Acceder al resultado, se espera solo uno
          console.log(res[0]);
      }
    },
    error: function () {
       console.log("error");
   }
  }
);
```

**Nota:** No es muy relevante, pero cambié `type` por `method`, que es la propiedad correcta, el primero funciona porque es un alias y podría ser declarado como obsoleto en el futuro.

Comment: Genio!! Me estaba rajando el bocho ya. era el var_dump!!!

Answer (score 0):

No puedes acceder a la respuesta porque es de tipo `string`, lo que debes hacer es convertirla a `JSON`. Hay dos formas, la primera es haciendo uso del `JSON.parse()`, de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax(
  {
    data: {dni:id},
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>User/Userajax/",
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function(res){
      let re = JSON.parse(res); // Aquí está el código añadido
      console.log(re[0].nombre); // Esto imprime "Emiliano"
      
    },
    error: function () {
       console.log("error");
   }
  }
);
```

La segunda forma, es especificar en tu `ajax` que la respuesta será recibida en `json`, haciendo uso del `dataType: 'json'` de la siguiente forma:

```
$.ajax(
  {
    data: {dni:id},
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>User/Userajax/",
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json', // Se especifica que el dato de respuesta es de tipo JSON
    success: function(res){
      
      console.log(res[0].nombre); // Esto imprime "Emiliano"
      
    },
    error: function () {
       console.log("error");
   }
  }
);
```

Comment: Cuando pongo datatype: 'json' no entra al success

Comment: la primera opcion el error es: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Comment: Has intentado devolver los datos desde el PHP usando `echo json_encode($rslt)` en lugar de `exit` ?

Comment: Si, sigue igual sin funcionar...

Comment: Ya sé cuál es el error, en la cuarta línea del archivo PHP, estás haciendo un `var_dump($_POST["dni"]);`, eso hace que se imprima un DNI antes del `JSON`, lo cuál hace que se mezclen y dé como resultado un json inválido, debes quitar esta línea y debería funcionar: `var_dump($_POST["dni"]);`

Answer (score 0):

Holaaa puedes añadir estas 2 lineas de codigo a tu codigo que esta en tu URL de ajax:

1. un Header que todo JSON necesita para ver que tipo de datos estas devolviendo
2. Puedes forzar a que devuelva el JSON QUE PUEDES COLCOCAR EN TU `json_encode` con `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`

`header('Content-Type: application/json'); $qry = $this->db->get(); $rslt = ($qry->num_rows() > 0) ? $qry->result("array") : "No se ha encontrado registros con el actual DNI"; exit(json_encode($rslt, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));`

Comment: No funciona Wilson... En el ajax no entra al success

Comment: Eso se debe a que no esta retornando un json valido... seria que muestres todo tu codigo de tu url de ajax asi podremos ver mejor donde esta el error, en tu preview 2 se ve claramente en tu consola que solo esta retornando texto eso es xq esta mal estructurado tu json

Comment: Ok ok ahi edito.

Comment: Okey en tu primera linea de codigo coloca esto `header('Content-Type: application/json');`